# Xia: damage on outfits and rolls

Tags: xia

After you apply damage to an outfit, and then activate the outfit multiple times (such as shields), do you apply the penalty to the total of all the dice, or to each individual die?

For exampl,e my Tier 1 shield has 1 damage. I activate two spaces (for 2d6). Would my total defense be 2d6-1 or 1d6-1 and 1d6-1?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You add the penalty to each individual use of the outfit. So yes, if you activate a d6 shield twice and that outfit has one damage on it you would -1 from both dice rolls individually